# Converting theme menu part of Yii 1 to Yii 2

Tags: url, menu, themes, yii2

Hi i am trying to convert the menu part of my theme from yii 1 to yii 2. 
Below is the code i use in Yii 1:

```
                <?php 

                $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu',array(
                    'htmlOptions' => array( 'class' => 'nav' ),
                    'activeCssClass'    => 'active',
                    'items'=>array(
                        array('label'=>'Home', 'url'=>array('/ABC/default')),
                        array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/auth/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->isGuest,'active'=>strpos(Yii::$app->request->requestUri, Yii::$app->createUrl('/auth/login'))===0),
                        array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::$app->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/auth/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::$app->user->isGuest,'active'=>strpos(Yii::$app->request->requestUri, Yii::$app->createUrl('/auth/logout'))===0),
                        array('label'=>'ABC Student List', 'url'=>array('/ABC/default/ABClist'),'active'=>strpos(Yii::$app->request->requestUri, Yii::$app->createUrl('/ABC/default/ABClist'))===0),
                        array('label'=>'ABC Administration', 'url'=>array('/ABC_ADMIN/default'), 'active'=>strpos(Yii::$app->request->requestUri, Yii::$app->createUrl('/ABC_ADMIN/default'))===0),
                        //array('label'=>'Login', 'url'=>array('/site/login'), 'visible'=>Yii::$app->user->isGuest),
                        //array('label'=>'Logout ('.Yii::$app->user->name.')', 'url'=>array('/site/logout'), 'visible'=>!Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
                    ),
                )); 
                ?>
```

This is the error i hit:
Getting unknown property: yii\web\Request::requestUri

Can someone assist me please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no such property `requestUri` in yii\web\Request.

Try using [yii\web\Request::url](http://stuff.cebe.cc/yii2docs/yii-web-request.html#$url-detail) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Menu widget(Yii 2). Example:

```
echo Menu::widget([
'items' => [
    // Important: you need to specify url as 'controller/action',
    // not just as 'controller' even if default action is used.
    ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['site/index']],
    // 'Products' menu item will be selected as long as the route is 'product/index'
    ['label' => 'Products', 'url' => ['product/index'], 'items' => [
        ['label' => 'New Arrivals', 'url' => ['product/index', 'tag' => 'new']],
        ['label' => 'Most Popular', 'url' => ['product/index', 'tag' => 'popular']],
    ]],
    ['label' => 'Login', 'url' => ['site/login'], 'visible' => Yii::$app->user->isGuest],
],
```

]);